# PDOStatement not returning result in Drupal views

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, pdo, drupal-7

I have a Drupal 7 view that should return one row, but is showing nothing found.

I ran the view in a debugger and noticed that `$stmt->fetch()` returns false, indicating nothing found.

At the same time I used server-side query logging to get the query being executed, and I find it returns one row as expected.

I double checked I was reading the right query using `$stmt->queryString` - it matches.

`$stmt->errorCode()` returns `00000`;

So it looks to me like the data is being lost between the server and PDO. Is this possible, and how can I debug or fix it?

Comment: error code `00000` means the query ran successfully. Was there anything bound to the query that possibly limited the result to zero rows?

Comment: Not that I can see. I keep coming back to the fact that the query logged by the server, which returned no data in PDO, returns 1 row when run via sqlYog. Different DB user, different connection parameters maybe, but same SQL.

Comment: Could you show some code or perhaps the query and any parameters? Without them there isn't much to go on here. The error code shows that no errors happened. So if there was a problem with the user, permissions or the query you would get an error.

Comment: Turns out to be a timezone issue. The query involes a date stored as timestamp. The value in the query where clause was `DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(field_date), '%Y-%m-%d') = '2016-05-06')` but in UTC the timestamp field was "2016-05-05 23:00:00". Querying for 2016-05-05 found it. The question now becomes why is Drupal storing and displaying the date as "2016-05-06" but a views query with that same date entered doesn't find it. That looks like a bug in Drupal date api or date views module so I'll do post there. Thanks anyway!